# Finding minimum sum from users input(without using function, lambda, map, etc)

Tags: python, python-3.x

The task looks like that :

**Enter n-quantity of any numbers from the keyboard.
Find the minimum among the sums of "previous" and "next" numbers.**

For example, for four numbers `2 4 5 3` of sums `2 + 4 = 6`, `4 + 5 = 9`, `5 + 3 = 8` the minimum will be `6`.

Here is what I've tried:

```
n = int(input('quantity of the numbers? '))
summ = 0
min_s = 0
for i in range(n):
    curr_num = int(input())
    if i > 0:
        summ = curr_num + prev_num
        print(summ)
        if summ < min_s:
            min_s = summ
    prev_num = curr_num
print(min_s)
```

Comment: Wouldn't the minimum in your example be 2 + 3? what does your output currently give

Comment: Please explain why no 'pythonic' methods (per your title); as these are more efficient than a loop.

Comment: @S3DEV this is homework obviously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set your min_s to 0, summ is never going to be smaller than min_s if you add two positive numbers.
You need to set your min_sum to the first sum you calculate, when you initialize it.

If you want a solution close to your code try this:

```
n = int(input('quantity of the numbers? '))
summ = 0
for i in range(n):
    curr_num = int(input())
    if i == 1:
        min_s = curr_num + prev_num
    if i > 1:
        summ = curr_num + prev_num
        print(summ)
        if summ < min_s:
            min_s = summ
    prev_num = curr_num
print("Minimum: ", min_s)
```

But as other posts mentioned, a list comprehension is a more compact way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension to find adjacent sums and the `min` function, you can do:

```py
nums = []
for i in range(n):
    nums.append(int(input())
#At this point nums is a list containing all user inputs.
print(min([nums[i] + nums[i + 1] for i in range(len(nums) - 1)]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! but I was trying to find something close to my code, but thanks in any case!

Answer (score 1):

Two things first.
One: you are trying to make the input a single number. However what you want is a list of numbers.
Two: Skipping the first step to determine prev_num is fine but there surely is a more elegant and efficient way to do this.
This is what i would do:

```
n = input('quantity of the numbers? ').split(',')
summ = 0
min_s = float('inf')
for i in range(0,len(n)-1):
    summ = int(n[i]) + int(n[i+1])
    print(summ)
    if summ < min_s:
        min_s = summ
print(min_s)
```

The input must now be a "list" of integers seperated by a comma. And i initialize min_s to the largest number possible, as if you would initialize it with 0, as long as the sum you found is bigger than that (which will always be the case for positive numbers) you will never find a new minimum value.

Comment: Thank you for your help! but I was trying to find something close to my code, but thanks in any case!

Answer (score 1):

Other answers that I am seeing so far used functions while you specifically asked a non function solution. This is your own code with a slightly difference. I add the if condition that define min_s as the sum of the first two inputted values. Your code's problem was that you defined min_s as zero which therefor never will be updated if all the sums of adjacent pairs are more than zero.

```
n = int(input('quantity of the numbers? '))
summ = 0
min_s = 0
print(min_s)
for i in range(n):
    curr_num = int(input())
    if i > 0:
        summ = curr_num + prev_num
        print("sum is: ", summ)
        if i == 1:
            min_s = summ
        if summ < min_s:
            min_s = summ
    prev_num = curr_num
print(min_s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just small edits of your code:

```
import sys

n = int(input('quantity of the numbers? '))
if n < 2:
    print("Not enough")
else:
    summ = 0
    min_s = sys.maxsize  # highest possible (not actually, but who cares :D )
    prev_num = int(input())
    for _ in range(n - 1):
        curr_num = int(input())
        summ = prev_num + curr_num
        if summ < min_s:
            min_s = summ
        prev_num = curr_num
    print(min_s)
```

---

What have been changed:

1. Added condition to not proceed if `n` lower than 2 (*pretty obvious why*);
2. Value of `min_s` should contain very high value to guarantee that it will be overwritten by first calculated sum, so I've used [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize);
3. Input of `prev_num` first time moved out of loop to not write additional conditions to skip first iteration inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
>>> i = input("Enter your numbers:").split() #for python 2 use raw_input
Enter your numbers:10 30 20 40
>>> l = [int(val)+int(i[ind+1]) for ind,val in enumerate(i) if ind < len(i)-1]
>>> l.sort()
>>> l[0]
40
>>> l
[40, 50, 60]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution without using any min function just an example

```
x = [2,4,5,3] # you can put your input in this list
y = []
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    temp = x[i] + x[i+1]
    y.append(temp)

minNum = 0
for j in range(len(y) - 1):
    if y[j] < y[j+1]:
        minNum = y[j]
print(minNum)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! but I was trying to find something close to my code, but thanks in any case!